# Mounting ISO image on mounted USB device

Tags: mount, iso

I've mounted a USB drive containing an ISO that's over 1TB in size and cannot be copied, because I don't have enough space.

Is it possible to mount this ISO even though it is in a mounted location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you are talking about a ISO-9660 filesystem image that is living on a file system that itself is on a USB drive.

This should be no problem, but how to do it depends on the OS you are using.

In 1988 I invented a method called `fbk` (file emulates block device) for SunOS-4.0 that allows to emulate a block device from data that is based on the content of a file.

10 years later, this has been copied under the (wrong) name "loopback driver" on Linux and a few years later, Sun Engineers implemented it under the name "lofi" on Solaris.

Since a while, on Solaris and Linux, it is very easy to use because the `mount` program detects when you provide a plain file instead of a block device name and handles the complex things for you, so just call:

```
mount -F hsfs /media/my/image.iso /mnt
```

on Solaris or:

```
mount -t iso9660 /media/my/image.iso /mnt
```

on Linux

Comment: The mount succeeded but I had to leave out `-t iso9660`. However I cannot copy data off the mounted ISO as I keep getting "unable to read fragment cache entry" or "unable to read page" errors. The ISO was from a disk recovered by `ddrescue`

Comment: If you cannot use `-t iso9660` this may be a different filesystem type, check the output of `mount` to find the used filesystem type. If you get such errors, you seem to have a defective filesystem. BTW: I've never seen a ISO-9660 filesystem of that size.

Comment: That was indeed the case. Ran `lsblk -f` and found out that it was an NTFS volume which I subsequently mounted.